# Installing R package ERROR: installing binary package failed

Tags: r, github

Complete newbie here, so there is probably something glaringly bad here. I created a Project following Hadley Wickham's book on R packages, and now I am trying add it to github for remote install ([repository for reference](https://github.com/alutterb/abcmlr)).

Running `devtools::install_github("alutterb/abcmlr")` generated the following output:

```
Downloading GitHub repo alutterb/abcmlr@master
√  checking for file 'C:\Users\amlut\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpMpn5uJ\remotes7146c405dd7\alutterb-abcmlr-918bf05/DESCRIPTION' ...
-  preparing 'abcmlr':
√  checking DESCRIPTION meta-information ... 
-  checking for LF line-endings in source and make files and shell scripts
-  checking for empty or unneeded directories
-  building 'abcmlr_0.1.0.tar.gz'

Installing package into ‘C:/Users/amlut/Documents/R/win-library/3.5’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
* installing *binary* package 'abcmlr' ...
cp: unknown option -- )
Try '/Rtools/bin/cp --help' for more information.
ERROR: installing binary package failed
* removing 'C:/Users/amlut/Documents/R/win-library/3.5/abcmlr'
In R CMD INSTALL
Error in i.p(...) : 
  (converted from warning) installation of package ‘C:/Users/amlut/AppData/Local/Temp/RtmpMpn5uJ/file71463953e7b/abcmlr_0.1.0.tar.gz’ had non-zero exit status
```

In my repository, I have a Linux executable that is to be used with `wsl` as well as an `.exe` file that is called in my R code. These may be the culprits, but I am not entirely sure. The error states that it failed to install the binary package, but `install_github()` takes a source package, so I am not sure what is going on. Any help is appreciated.

Thank you.

EDIT: This problem is solved. It was because of a line in my `DESCRIPTION` file that had to do with `Built`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your `%PATH%` and type: `where cp`.

Another `cp` (like one from the Git for Windows distribution) might overshadow the RTools `cp`, which might explain the error message.

---

As [commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56958676/installing-r-package-error-installing-binary-package-failed/56963687#comment100485938_56963687) by the [OP hkj447](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11171682/hkj447), the error was trigger by a line in the `DESCRIPTION` file:

```
Built: R 3.5.3; ; 2019-06-14 21:17:43 UTC; windows
```

As seen [in this thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/embed/#!topic/rdevtools/qxA5d9-9gPE):

> You have a field called '`Built:`' in your package's `DESCRIPTION` file;
>   R normally tries to inject that field itself when it builds your package from sources.
>
> I deleted "`Built`"'s line in `DESCRIPTION` and then installed again.
>   This time, no error appeared.

Comment: @hkj447 On what version of Windows are you launching that process? In what shell (WSL, DOS, Powershell)? With what Git for Windows installed? 2.22? With what `%PATH%`?

Comment: I figured it out actually. It was a line in my `DESCRIPTION` file.

Comment: Do you know which line?

Comment: `Built: R 3.5.3; ; 2019-06-14 21:17:43 UTC; windows`

Comment: @hkj447 OK. I have edited and documented the answer accordingly.