# Install R package ERROR installing binary package failed

Tags: r, devtools, r-package, cran

I'm newbie for R and I built my R package for my users that built without error.
When I install on Windows with `devtools::install_local(path = "MyPackage.zip", dependencies = TRUE)`.
I got error
`* installing *binary* package 'MyPackage' ... cp: unknown option -- ) Try '/usr/bin/cp --help' for more information. ERROR: installing binary package failed`
After some search I found this thread [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56958676/installing-r-package-error-installing-binary-package-failed)
but I have no `Built:` in my `DESCRIPTION` file.

Anyone please can help me how to solve these ?

Comment: Not sure we can help much without more information on the package. Is it in a public repo or available for download somewhere?

Comment: Sorry, It 's my own developed package. It's R Shiny App.